# is multiprocessing similar to multithreading?

Tags: computer-science

This question is not specific to any programming language but i want to know WHAT IS THE EXACT DIFFERENCE BETWEEN MULTIPROCESSING AND MULTITHREADING. These two terms often generate a confusion about their understanding.Someone please do explain them, their differences and similarities too.

Comment: Multiprocessing isn't a common term. Multiprocessor refers to the CPU hardware, whereas multithreading is usually used to describe software (but can be done as hardware processes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-Threading refers to an application with multiple threads running with in a process,
where as Multi-Processing refers to an application organized across multiple OS-level processes.

Comment: In multiprocessor systems, can it be that different threads of a same process are running on different processors ?

Comment: Different threads of a single process will run concurrently on a single processor. I think one thread of a particular process may not run in another process.

Comment: if other processors are free(not busy) then can different threads of single process be assigned different processors or always assigned single processor, doesn't matter whether other processors are free or not?

Comment: I think this explanation will clear your doubt...
Multiprocessing : Several jobs can run at the same time.
Multi-threading : Same job can be broken logically and executed simultaneously and the results are combined at the end of processing

Comment: It says that different threads can be assigned different processors(it they are free) because at the end they(threads) are executed simultaneously.Do you agree to this ?

Comment: yeah i am getting the concept.

Comment: yeah! i have got the concept.Different threads can be assigned different processors(if free) because the number of threads actually running depends on the no. of CPUs(processors) available, though all threads are runnable. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Its my pleasure @user2181750

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiprocessing and multithreading on one single processor.

The difference is in memory space :

- Two threads within the same process can share memory space and make operations on same data.
- Two processes are fully independent in memory usage. they can though synchronize their exacution using semaphores, monitors or other known methods.

Comment: In multiprocessor systems ,can different threads of a same process be assigned different processors(if they are free) individually or always assigned a single processor, doesn't matter whether other processors are free or not ?

Comment: Your answer is also helpful to me. Thanks

Comment: Of course, you can have a process using many threads, each on a specific processor. But one thread instance is executed by one processor at once.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing and multithreading are two different techniques of sharing a task.

Multiprocessing : here multiple processes runs in parallel and can share common resource.

Multithreading : here more then one thread (part of a single process) runs in parallel.